# Selecting textbox on focus using jQuery isn't working in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four text-boxes on a page with maxlength 4. My goal is that when a user fills the first text box the focus automatically moves to another text box. The method I wrote works fine in all web browsers but not in mobile browsers.

The markup I'm using:

```
<input tabindex="3" type="text" id="cnumber1" class="inputBx ccNumber" style="width:57px;margin-left: 11px!important" maxlength="4" size="4" autocomplete="off" />
        <input tabindex="4" type="text" id="cnumber2" class="ccNumber" style="width:57px;"  maxlength="4" size="4" autocomplete="off"/>
        <input tabindex="5" type="text" id="cnumber3" class="ccNumber" style="width:56px;"  maxlength="4" size="4" autocomplete="off"/>
        <input tabindex="6" type="text" id="cnumber4" class="ccNumber" style="width:56px;"  maxlength="4" size="4" autocomplete="off"/>
```

The Jquery method I'm using:

```
(function($) {
  $.switchFocus = function($this) {
    $this.unbind('keyup');
    $this.each(function() {
      $(this).keyup(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
        inputVal = $this.val(),
        iLen = inputVal.length,
        $nextEle = $this.next();
        if (iLen == $this.attr("size") && $nextEle.length > 0){
          if($nextEle.val().length === 0)
            $nextEle.focus();
        }
      });
    });
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Could I please get some help as to why this is happening with mobile browsers?

Comment: In which mobile browsers are you trying?

Comment: @Ocanal I am using safari in iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a bug for some mobile browsers, but this method should solve your problem, try it,

```
(function($) {
  $.switchFocus = function($this) {
    $this.unbind('keyup');
    $this.each(function() {
      $(this).keyup(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
        inputVal = $this.val(),
        iLen = inputVal.length,
        $nextEle = $this.next();
        if (iLen == $this.attr("size") && $nextEle.length > 0){
          if($nextEle.val().length === 0)
            $nextEle.focus();
            setTimeout(function(){$nextEle.focus()},0);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}(jQuery));
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ocanal/ZL3gz/1/)